# Socket.io clients seem to connect to different sockets on the same server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Hi I'm running a standard (example) socket.io chatroom, but I'm running into a problem I'm not sure how to debug.

The chatroom seems to functioning normally, clients can broadcast their messages, but occasionally on connection it is as if they are alone in the chatroom when they are not -- other clients don't see their presence or messages. It frequently happens when clients are not joining the socket around the same time.

It is as if they've connected to an entirely different socket.

I think it might be something to do with cookies and sessions. If the clients clear their sessions they are reunited in the chat.

Perhaps on (or before) connection I could clear session data? How?

Comment: I don't think we can help you without seeing how your code works.  We need to see how you identify a particular user so you know what chatroom to put them in when they reconnect and see what you're using session data for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured it out, I was right *and* wrong.

I think the clients **were** connecting to 'entirely different sockets' but it had nothing much to do with cookies and sessions:

I discovered (due to some other really weird bugs) by a study of running processes that *somehow* an old version of the socket.io server script was clinging to life in the background for some time. I expect clients were connecting to one of the two io server scripts randomly: not good. Working in a sense, but in separate worlds.

Killing those rogue processes seems to have fixed a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for a chat server that clients connect on the same IP and port. Typically, there is a requirement that they connect to the same server, which must maintain a list of client connections to enable chat between them.

Chat works like this:

Server sets up a ServerSocket to accept connections. Clients connect, and these connections are stored on the Server in an array, object or some other form. When the server gets a message event from one of the clients, this message is then broadcast to all the other clients.

Thus, if you have one client who is not receiving any messages and appears to be in an empty room, the issue is likely that they are somehow not part of the same collection of connected clients, part of the same chat app, or not connected at all.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @ControlAltDel -- I was confused by what you were saying about IP and ports because I knew those were not at fault in this case, but you were right 'not part of the same collection of connected clients' -- due to a duplicate process.